# Show that the limit does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that the function 
$$f(x,y)=(xy)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$ 
is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

What I have done is found expression for the partial derivatives in order to find the gradient, and from first principles I was able to show that:

$$ (\nabla f)(0,0)=(0,0) $$

so I use the limit expression for differentiability and show that it is not zero:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{| f(x,y)-f(0,0)-(\nabla f)(0,0)\cdot(x,y)^T  |}{|(x,y)-(0,0)|}$$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{| (xy)^{\frac{1}{3}} -0 - 0 |}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{| (xy)^{\frac{1}{3}}|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

but I am stuck at this point as I am not able to show that this is discontinuous at $(0,0)$

Comment: If $(x,y)=(h,h)$, then your expression is $h^{2/3}/h=h^{-1/3}$. This clearly does not converge to 0 as $h\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Very obvious, I should have seen that..

Answer (score 1):

If we take the limit along the line $y=x$ we get that the limit is:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times x^{-\frac{1}{3}} \rightarrow \infty$$

so since the limit does not converge to $0$, the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: One comment to be aware of: it is tempting to look for limits along lines, but it is possible to carefully cook up examples (not this specific one here) that converge along every line, but which still fail to converge if $(0,0)$ is approached along some other sequence of points.